# Editing Original DataFrame After Making a Copy but Before Editing the Copy Changes the Copy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to understand how copying a pandas data frame works. When I assign a copy of an object in python I am not used to changes to the original object affecting copies of that object. For example:

```
x = 3
y = x
x = 4
print(y)
3
```

While `x` has subsequently been changed, y remains the same. In contrast, when I make changes to a pandas `df` after assigning it to a copy `df1` the copy is also affected by changes to the original DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def minusone(x):
    return int(x) - 1

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30,40,50], "B": [20, 30, 10, 40, 50], "C": [32, 234, 23, 23, 42523]})

df1 = df


print(df1['A'])

0    10
1    20
2    30
3    40
4    50
Name: A, dtype: int64

df['A'] = np.vectorize(minusone)(df['A'])

print(df1['A'])

0     9
1    19
2    29
3    39
4    49
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

The solution appears to be making a deep copy with `copy.deepcopy()`, but because this behavior is different from the behavior I am used to in python I was wondering if someone could explain what the reasoning behind this difference is or if it is a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your first example, you did not make a change to the value of `x`.  You assigned a *new* value to `x`.

In your second example, you did modify the value of `df`, by changing one of its columns.

You can see the effect with builtin types too:

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = x
>>> x.append(1)
>>> y
[1]
```

The behavior is not specific to Pandas; it is fundamental to Python.  There are many, many questions on this site about this same issue, all stemming from the same misunderstanding.  The syntax

```
barename = value
```

**does not have the same behavior as any other construct in Python**.

When using `name[key] = value`, or `name.attr = value` or `name.methodcall()`, you may be mutating the value of the object referred to by `name`, you may be copying something, etc.  By using `name = value` (where `name` is a single identifier, no dots, no brackets, etc.), you never mutate anything, and never copy anything.

In your first example, you used the syntax `x = ...`.  In your second example, you used the syntax `df['A'] = ...`.  These are not the same syntax, so you can't assume they have the same behavior.

The way to make a copy depends on the kind of object you're trying to copy.  For your case, use `df1 = df.copy()`.